# Curl command doesn't pass param value with #

Tags: linux, curl

I'm using the next curl command:

curl --silent --insecure --max-time 10000 -X POST -G 'https://1.1.1.1:8443/prefix' -d username=user -d password=blabla12#

and for some reason, my server gets the password without the #.(blabla12) and the authentication is failing.
How can I provide a value with # as part of my curl command?

Comment: `#` is a special character for the shell. Use quotes.

Comment: How? I tried -d "password=blabla12#" and I tried -d 'password=blabla12#'

Comment: um sorry, `#` is not special for the shell, it was my brain fart.

Comment: `#` is only special if separated by whitespace (it starts a comment). But I can confirm your finding with httpbin.org. Let me find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -G -XPOST 'https://httpbin.org/post' -d 'key=value#'` is identical to running `curl -XPOST 'https://httpbin.org/post?key=value#'`. `#` separates the [Fragment-id](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html) from the rest of the URL.

This becomes even more obvious with calls such as `curl -G -XPOST 'https://httpbin.org/post' -d 'a=b#c' -d 'd=e' -d 'f=g'` – your backend will only receive `a=b`, everything else is part of the fragment-id. You can run `curl -v` to see the actual request (which will only include the query string up to and excluding the first hash sign).

The solution? Make it impossible to confuse the hash sign with the fragment-id separator by percent-encoding it:

```
curl -G -XPOST 'https://httpbin.org/post' -d 'key=value%23'
curl -XPOST 'https://httpbin.org/post?key=value%23'
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a special character in URI-reference. It delimits a fragment. See [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396#appendix-A) (note the link itself contains a `#`). `curl` will not send `#` or anything that follows as a part of a request.

You should URL-encode `#` (use `%23`) if you want it to be treated as a part of the request. Note the server will see `%23`, not `#`. It should URL-decode the string before using it.

Of course sending passwords as plain text is the last thing you want to do in life.

Comment: the password is just example